# Cannot disable manual commits on Kafka message using Spring-integration-kafka in Spring-Boot App

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-integration, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

As I am new to kafka, my group is using Spring-Integration-kafka:2.0.0.RELEASE on a Spring-boot application. I was able to consume kafka message with my KafkaConsumer based on this example [here](http://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/09/23/spring-kafka-tutorial/).

For this spring-boot application, I have my Application.java

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import hello.notification.Listener;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    private Listener listener;

    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        this.listener.countDownLatch1.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is my KafkaConsumerConfig.java

```
package hello.notification;

import ....; //different imports

@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
    @Bean
    KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(1);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(3000);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> propsMap = new HashMap<>();
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group1");
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        //propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 100);
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 6000);
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(propsMap);
    }

    @Bean
    public Listener listener() {
        return new Listener();
    }
}
```

and finally my Listener.java

```
package hello.notification;

import ...; // different imports

public class Listener {

    public final CountDownLatch countDownLatch1 = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @KafkaListener(topics = "topic1")
    public void listen(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record, Acknowledgment ack) {
        System.out.println(record + " and " + ack);
                // Place holder for "ack.acknowledge();"
        countDownLatch1.countDown();
    } 
}
```

my questions are:

1) In ConsumerConfig settings, I've already set "ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG" to **false** and commented out "ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG", why does it still commits automatically?(as I no longer would see the message if I restart my spring-boot app- I would expect it to try to resend until it's been committed)

2) In order to commit manually, I think I just need to add ack.acknowledge() inside my Listener.listen(please see place-holder)? Is there anything else that I would need other than this to ensure this is a manual commit?

3) I would like to have the simplest/cleanest kafkaconsumer, I wonder if you think what I have is the simplest way, originally I was looking for singlethreaded consumer but there are not a lot of examples out there so I stick with the concurrent listener.

Thanks for all of your help and inputs!

Answer (score 7):

> why does it still commits automatically?

Just because by default `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` is supplied with:

```
private AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode ackMode = AckMode.BATCH;
```

> Is there anything else that I would need other than this to ensure this is a manual commit?

You have to switch to the

```
ContainerProperties.setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.MANUAL)
```

> I wonder if you think what I have is the simplest way

That's correct. Just only need to get used to.

See [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#committing-offsets) for more info

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. from what you said, it sounds like the only change I need to make in order to do manual commit, is in the "KafkaConsumerConfig.java" file. I tried adding "factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);"  right before I return my factory and retried but it didn't work, on restart my message is still not re-appearing. May I ask if you can provide some sample using my above code? Thanks!

Comment: Well, try to add `propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");` to `consumerFactory` props. By default it is `latest`: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs.

Comment: I added propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest"); and also in Listener class we ensured that we implements AcknowledgingMessageListener and override onMessage method but still no luck with having the message come back, it feels like it is automatically committing by itself by end of onMessage():
public class Listener implements AcknowledgingMessageListener<String, String>{
    @Override
    public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record, Acknowledgment ack) {
        System.out.println(record + " and " + ack);
    } 
}

Comment: I assume you mean that you would like to have the message one more time on the next poll iteration, but that isn't a case with Kafka. There is some internal state in the Consumer to keep an `index` of the log. You can get it again after app restart.

Comment: Yes,kinda..my goal is to create a clean KafkaConsumer where it won't commit unless I tell it to(based on a condition & by using ack.acknowledge()). So i've created one similar to above code,and to test that consumer must be committed manual by me,i purposely do not use ack.acknowledge() to force it to resend me the same msg again upon next restart but i have yet to find a solution to it. Although i am not committing it(i did not use ack.acknowledge()), the msg doesn't come back when i restart my app..which means that it has been committed..does that make sense?any sample you can provide?Thanks

Comment: @RC, have you got any solution for manual commit in kafka using spring boot?

Comment: @RC, It will be a great help if you can provide any sample code. Because I didn't found a proper documentation for manual commit in kafka using spring boot.